# How to use default field values for ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django

I'm just starting to learn Django and building a simple blog with it.
So i have two models `Post` and `PostStatistics`. When ever i add a new post, i want that PostStatistics contains all specified default values. How can i achieve this correctly?

models.py

```
class PostStatistics(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    post_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    post_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    post_favorites = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    statistics = models.ForeignKey(PostStatistics, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py

```
def add_post(request: HttpRequest):
    form = PostForm(request.POST)
    is_draft = True if form.data.get("draft") == "on" else False
    post = Post(
        title=form.data["title"],
        body=form.data["post"],
        user=request.user,
        draft=is_draft,
        statistics = PostStatistics() -> this is not correct
    )
    post.save()
    return redirect("post")
```

At the moment i get `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new one:

```
def add_post(request: HttpRequest):
    form = PostForm(request.POST)
    is_draft = form.data.get('draft') == 'on'
    post_statistics = PostStatistics.objects.create()
    Post.objects.create(
        title=form.data['title'],
        body=form.data['post'],
        user=request.user,
        draft=is_draft,
        statistics = post_statistics
    )
    return redirect('post')
```

It however does not make much sense to store the statistics in a separate model, since there is a clear one-to-one relation, and thus the statistics can be stored in the `Post` model.

Furthermore you can use the form to validate the input and also create the object (or at least parts of it). A better modeling thus might be:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    post_views = models.IntegerField(default=0, editable=False)
    post_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0, editable=False)
    post_favorites = models.IntegerField(default=0, editable=False)
```

and then work with a `ModelForm` where you let the form do all the proper validation and cleaning:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def add_post(request: HttpRequest):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('post')
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'name-of-some-template.html', {'form': form})
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).